# Why can't Might Guy get his legs back?

Tags: naruto

After the Fourth Great Ninja War, both Naruto and Sasuke lost an arm and Might Guy lost his legs (after awakening 8 gates). Tsunade and the team then built arms for Sasuke/Naruto using Hashirama cells.

Why didn't they chop Guy's legs and put Hashirama legs as well? Is it because Hashirama cells are not compatible?

Comment: The same reason why the hashirama cells won't becomes trees when Naruto uses kurama chakra (plot holes)

Comment: I don't think that his problem is in the legs, but rather in his spine... Replacing them  wouldn't work. And I think creating a spinal cord replacement might be a little trickier.

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore Zetsu became trees when they died due to Naruto's abundant yang energy from Kurama's Yang half. Naruto not only resolved that issue after the war, but he also is still alive and able to control the chakra preventing it from turning into a tree. That would also be why Danzo didn't turn into a tree, and then he did, because he was so weak he couldn't control his chakra and so lost control of the arm.

Comment: Hashirama, reason for all plotholes ;-)

Comment: As I understand it was just just the one leg that got messed up and he didn't lose either entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So why does Tsunade still not create a leg for Might Guy?**

If we want to create a leg for Might Guy, this means that his body needs to strong enough to handle the Hashirama Cells. Implementing the Hashirama Cells has his own risk. Currently Might Guy's body is not compatible with the Hashirama Cells because his body is not strong as before. If we force Might Guy to implement the Hashirama Cells, the consequences will be the same as Danzo.

Just like [@TheTrue7thHokage](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/50801/19307) said, Might Guy's body was totally destroyed and even almost died after the fight with Madara, unlike Sasuke and Naruto. (Only their hands were gone, not their entire bodies.)

Remember Danzo? His body also implemented the Hashirama Cells, but in the fight between Danzo and Sasuke, he needed to cut off his own arm in order to not let the cells devour him. **At this state, Danzo is already very weakened.**

[image: Danzo's arm goes berserk]

As you can see with the red rectangle mark I have placed, this is the explanation for why Might Guy does not have his legs back. They are scared this case will happen with Might Guy.

**Ok now let's talk about Naruto. Why can he can handle the Hashirama Cells?**

At this state, Naruto is a very strong person: he has his Kurama's power, he has the Six Path Power, and he also knows how to use Sage mode. Obviously he is stronger than anyone in that world. So of course his body can sustain the cells.

Answer (score 3):

Tsunade could not fix Guy’s legs because his body and his nerves were destroyed from fighting with Madara. Guy's body was really damaged and way worse than Sasuke and Naruto's damage.

There is a certain point where if it's reached, then there is no going back from it, plus the Uzumaki clan has special healing powers, for example Karin.

But Sasuke *on the other hand*, didn't want to have his body healed, because it would feel like his sins are being forgiven with no consequences, especially after he did a lot of bad things to the Hidden Leaf Village.

Comment: basically they weren't able to do it because might guy destroyed his leg, but Naruto's and Sasuke's hands were cut off; not ripped off.

Comment: That would make less sense, because having Guy get his legs amputated and then replaced with new ones would completely skip over the damage by removing it entirely. Rather the problem has to be something besides damage, like not being able to accept a Hashirama transplant.

Answer (score 0):

Because those body parts made from hashirama cells required that the user was compatible with hashiramas chakra and or have a very strong chakra control and remember that Guy has zero chakra control... Though naruto could've done it for him like he did with kawakis arm...   Also guy accepted his fate, he could also use  robotic prosthetics... The main reason is that the plot wants him that way